# What does 'to hedge on' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Memorial Sloan-Kettering Cancer Center President and CEO Dr. Craig Thompson (not to be confused with Mayo's Thompson) **hedges on** the metabolic theory of cancer. "While the arguments raised [by Seyfried and others] have been considered by the growing field of cancer metabolism, most investigators have moved on to consider other explanations for the observations,"

What does 'to hedge on' mean in this context?  I've read OED's entry on 'hedge' and couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to separate **hedge** and **on**.

To **hedge** is to be noncommittal and acknowledge or see both sides to an argument.

**Hedging on** is to hedge about something in particular (the object of the **on**)

Dr Craig Thompson is **hedging** ***on*** one of the theories of cancer.
He is not saying that that theory is the only explanation.